# React Hook Form with Nested Input fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

Summarise:
An radio button group nested inside another group updates the parent group's value

Details:
I am using Form Context and pass the control to each inputs
For display purpose, I need to put a radio group within another radio group, creating a nested radio group:

```
const watchParentGroup = methods.watch('ParentGroup');
...
<RadioGroup controllerName="ParentGroup">
    <RadioButton value="1" name="ParentGroup" style={{ marginRight: 15 }}>
        <span>I am parent's button</span>
        {parseInt(watchParentGroup, 10) === 1 && (
            <RadioGroup controllerName="ChildGroup">
                <RadioButton value="a" name="ChildGroup" style={{ marginRight: 15 }}>
                    <span>I am child's button</span>
                </RadioButton>
            </RadioGroup>
        )}
    </RadioButton>
    ...
</RadioGroup>
```

And here's the RadioButton and RadioGroup:

```
import { Controller, useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form';
import React from 'react';
import { Radio, useRadioState, RadioGroup as PrettyRadioGroup } from 'pretty-checkbox-react';

const RadioGroup = ({ children }) => {
  const radio = useRadioState();

  const radios = React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
    return React.cloneElement(child, { radio });
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <PrettyRadioGroup {...radio}>{radios}</PrettyRadioGroup>
    </div>
  );
};

const RadioButton = ({ radio, name, value, children, style }) => {
  const { control } = useFormContext();
  return (
    <Controller
      as={(
        <label style={style}>
          <Radio value={value} name={name} {...radio} />
          {children}
        </label>
      )}
      name={name}
      control={control}
    />
  );
};
```

Suppose I click on Parent group's first button, watchParentGroup results in 1 and the child group will render. However when I click on the child's options, watchParentGroup is also updated to 'a' and the child group is removed as a result.

How should I set up the form so that the ChildGroup does not affect ParentGroup's value?